# Rails PayPal adaptive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using [paypal_adaptive](https://github.com/tc/paypal_adaptive) gem and having some problems.
This is my code in config/paypal_adaptive.yml:

```
development:
  environment: "sandbox"
  username: "x@gmail.com"
  password: "xxx"
  signature: "xxx"
  application_id: "APP-80W284485P519543T"

test:
  environment: "sandbox"
  username: "x@gmail.com"
  password: "xxx"
  signature: "xxx"
  application_id: "APP-80W284485P519543T"

enviorment:
  environment: "sandbox"
  username: "x@gmail.com"
  password: "xxx"
  signature: "xxxx"
  application_id: "APP-80W284485P519543T"
```

of course the XXX is the real details. I also tried with the API credentials that were given me, didn't work either way.
Here's the controller code which controls the payment:

> >
>   pay_request = PaypalAdaptive::Request.new

```
data = {
"returnUrl" => "http://localhost:3000/payments/completed_payment_request", 
"requestEnvelope" => {"errorLanguage" => "en_US"},
"currencyCode"=>"USD",  
"receiverList"=>{"receiver"=>[{"email"=>"xxx@gmail.com", "amount"=>"10.00"}]},
"cancelUrl"=>"http://localhost:3000/payments/canceled_payment_request",
"actionType"=>"PAY",
"ipnNotificationUrl"=>"http://localhost:3000/payments/ipn_notification"
}

@pay_response = pay_request.pay(data)
```

I am getting the following array (which contains the error) when trying to output pay_response:

> >
>   ["responseEnvelope", {"timestamp"=>"2011-05-03T12:00:54.107-07:00", "ack"=>"Failure", "correlationId"=>"242e1fc31cf18", "build"=>"1846084"}]     ["error", [{"errorId"=>"560022", "domain"=>"PLATFORM", "subdomain"=>"Application", "severity"=>"Error", "category"=>"Application", "message"=>"The X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID header contains an invalid value", "parameter"=>["X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID"]}]]

I am really hopeless. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had the same issue, but it was caused by incorrect yaml syntax in my  paypal_adaptive.yml file. Fixing it and restarting application seems to fix the issue

Comment: Hey Adam, I'm doing the same thing, and I was wondering where you found/got that application id. It doesn't appear with the rest of my API credentials in the sandbox. Or is this just for production?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually I never got it to work, I was doing the payment stuff by myself. Then I figured I didn't reset my server after editing the YAML! :D

Thanks anyways!

Comment: -1: answer with "Thanks" should come at the end... as is in natural communication.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you restart the rails server after changing the key

Answer (score 1):

The Answer is, Your post url, check that your posting to the Sandbox or live
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay
if your using a Sandbox ID make sure your using a Sandbox url..

Answer (score 0):

Is that the same format as your YAML or is it properly indented?
Try reformatting your YAML. I've had similar problems in the past due to malformed YAML.