# paypal_adaptive gem not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using papal_adaptive gem. I provided my paypal sandbox account details in papal_adaptive.yml file.  When I call `pay_request = PaypalAdaptive::Request.new`, it throws the error below:

```
    You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
    You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
    The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
```

Comment: If you are using a gem, then you are talking about Ruby & Ruby on Rails, right? What version are you using? Do you have this error in which controller?

Comment: Hi, I am using ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.7 in windows system.

Comment: The same error with also adaptive_pay gem comes.

Comment: Is any one know about paypal_adaptive gem.

Comment: I found this: http://tommy.chheng.com/2009/12/29/paypal-adaptive-ruby-gem-released/ Maybe it could help you.

Comment: I followed same steps in that url but I did not find any solution .

Comment: Have you looked into StackOverflow for other question like yours? For example this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874415/rails-paypal-adaptive

Comment: Have you read this doc? http://rubydoc.info/gems/astrails-paypal_adaptive/0.1.4/file/README.markdown

Comment: Hi Alberts there is no use , let me know any other solution .

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is an old thread, but I just wanted to answer your question since I stumbled upon it: when you get this error with the paypal_adaptive gem it is more than likely an error in the hashes in the request you sent to PayPal: check your logs, there should be some indication of which hash is bad.